# Get count of responses from matrix of survey answers

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that stores responses to well-being questions. The structure is:

```
Wellbeing(WellbeingId, WellbeingDate, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7...)

+------------+---------------+----+----+----+
|WellbeingId | WellbeingDate | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |...
+============+===============+====+====+====+
|1           | 01/01/2015    | 1  | 1  | 5  |
+------------+---------------+----+----+----+
|2           | 10/01/2015    | 3  | 3  | 2  |
+------------+---------------+----+----+----+
|3           | 18/01/2015    | 2  | 4  | 1  |
+------------+---------------+----+----+----+
```

WellbeingResponses(ResponseId, ResponseText)

```
+-----------+---------------------+
|ResponseId | ResponseText        |
+===========+=====================+
|1          | 'None of the Time'  |
+-----------+---------------------+
|2          | 'Rarely'            |
+-----------+---------------------+
|3          | 'Sometimes'         |
+-----------+---------------------+
|4          | 'Most of the time'  |
+-----------+---------------------+
|5          | 'All of the time'   |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

Each `Q` column has a value between `1` and `5` inclusive. These values are linked to another table for the associated text (ie. 1 = Not very much, 5 = All the time etc.)

I would like to get the data from SQL Server as a total count for each of the possible response values like so:

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|Response           | Q1 Total | Q2 Total | Q3 Total ...|
+===================+==========+==========+=============+
|'None of the Time' | 500      | 256      | 546         |
+-------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|'Rarely'           | 500      | 256      | 546         |
+-------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|'Sometimes'        | 500      | 256      | 546         |
+-------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

I have tried selecting out the individual bits of data and using union all it but that just stacks the data as a count of each of the 5 values from each of the 7 "Q" columns, also tried adapting a pivot query I found on SO somewhere but cant figure that out when trying to use dynamic data for the columns selecting them from the `WellbeingResponses` table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** : Added well-being responses table.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a bit of a mess with your `Wellbeing` table. I'd really recommend rewriting this table to be normalized so you can avoid having to perform multiple joins or even unpivoting the data to get the desired result you want.

Since your current table is denormalized, you've got to convert the data to make it workable, then aggregate it, finally repivot it into your final desired result. It's going to be a bit of a mess but there are several ways that you can do this.

One way that you can get the result is to unpivot your `wellbeing` table so the data is normalized.  Since you are using SQL Server you can use the `UNPIVOT` function or, depending on version, you can use `CROSS APPLY`.  The code to convert your multiple columns into multiple rows will be:

```
select col, value
from wellbeing
cross apply
(
  select 'Q1', Q1 union all
  select 'Q2', Q2 union all
  select 'Q3', Q3
) c (col, value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5944/3). This gets your data in the format:

```
| COL | VALUE |
|-----|-------|
|  Q1 |     1 |
|  Q2 |     1 |
|  Q3 |     5 |
|  Q1 |     3 |
|  Q2 |     3 |
```

Now the data can be easily joined on with your other table:

```
select r.ResponseText, d.col
from WellbeingResponses r
left join
(
  select col, value
  from wellbeing
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Q1', Q1 union all
    select 'Q2', Q2 union all
    select 'Q3', Q3
  ) c (col, value)
) d
  on r.responseid = d.value
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5944/2). Once you've got a list of each question and the response, you can aggregate it and pivot the totals:

```
select ResponseText, q1, q2, q3
from
(
  select r.ResponseText, d.col
  from WellbeingResponses r
  left join
  (
    select col, value
    from wellbeing
    cross apply
    (
      select 'Q1', Q1 union all
      select 'Q2', Q2 union all
      select 'Q3', Q3
    ) c (col, value)
  ) d
    on r.responseid = d.value
) s
pivot
(
  count(col)
  for col in (Q1, Q2, Q3)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5944/4).

An alternative way to get the result would be to perform multiple joins on your `wellbeing` table. Each join would be on the `question` column:

```
select r.responsetext,
  Q1Total = count(w1.q1),
  Q2Total = count(w2.q2),
  Q3Total = count(w3.q3)
from WellbeingResponses r
left join wellbeing w1
  on r.responseid = w1.q1
left join wellbeing w2
  on r.responseid = w2.q2
left join wellbeing w3
  on r.responseid = w3.q3
group by r.responsetext;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5944/9). Both versions will give a result:

```
|     RESPONSETEXT | Q1TOTAL | Q2TOTAL | Q3TOTAL |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|
|  All of the time |       0 |       0 |       1 |
| Most of the time |       0 |       1 |       0 |
| None of the Time |       1 |       1 |       1 |
|           Rarely |       1 |       0 |       1 |
|        Sometimes |       1 |       1 |       0 |
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll look into cross apply (not used it being a newbie to database querying in general). I may have to see if I can restructure the database to make manipulation easier then...although it'll mean changing a few things on the website.

Comment: @bowfinger I added an alternative solution, using multiple joins. The biggest issue is with your current structure, it's difficult to work with.

Comment: I think that's the way I originally tried to do it but I selected from the Wellbeing table first and then inner joined (as no values can ever be null) to the WellbeingResponses table. It just looked nasty and inefficient...probably all the more reason for a restructure. In your original answer, where would I add an ORDER BY clause to get the response text in order 1 - 5?

Comment: @bowfinger You can include the `responseid` in the subquery and then order by it - see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5944/10

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Think I need to brush up on my SQL!